# Angular - Mark option in select dropdown as selected by default

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm having issues with auto-setting the correct option as `selected`. I **suspect** that the reason might be because of Angular not understanding that `price.currency` and `let currency of currencies` is the same object.

```
<select [(ngModel)]="price.currency" class="form-control">
    <option *ngFor="let currency of currencies" [ngValue]="currency">
        {{currency.iso_code}}
    </option>
</select>
```

I have created model classes for both `price` and for `currency` as you can see here:

```
export class ProductPrice {
    id: number;
    product: number;
    price: number;
    taxrule: Taxrule;
    currency: Currency;
}
```

When I fetch the list of `currencies` I cast it to to a list of `Currency[]`.

Lastly... I also tried adding the `[selected]="price.currency.id == currency.id"` argument to the `<option>` without any result. Probably because `ngValue` overrides it.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you figured, the `price.currency` cannot be recognized from the `currencies` array. You can bind these two values, by creating reference between these two. It can be done after you have received currencies (and `price`), for example like this:

```
this.price.currency = this.currencies.find(x => x.id == this.price.currency.id)
```

Here's a **[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/0lVFgKQdNyQzrDIJWggy?p=preview)**

Comment: This was the solution I was looking for. Couldn't find it anywhere else! Good job. Thanks.